# When i was making discord bot ban users and kick users is not working correctly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When i was making discord bot ban users and kick users is not working correctly because it can kick by users without an permissions

```
@bot.tree.command(name="kick", description="Kicking Other Users With My Hammer Tool")
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason: str = None):
    """Kick a member from the server."""
    if not reason:
        reason = "No reason given."
    try:
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
        embed = Embed(title="Kicking", color=discord.Color.red())
        embed.add_field(name="Kick Users", value=f"This User: {member.mention} is kicked for: ``{reason}``", inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="https://turpincheat.glitch.me  --  İlyax.")
        await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
        channel_id = 1038757871246127134
        channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send("Üzgünüm, bu işlemi gerçekleştirmek için yeterli yetkiye sahip değilim.")



@bot.tree.command(name="ban", description="Banning Other Users With My Hammer Tool")
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)  # Ban komutunu sadece ban_members yetkisi olan kullanıcıların kullanabilmesini sağlar
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason: str = None):
  if ctx.author.guild_permissions.kick_members:
    if not reason:
      reason = "Not reason Given (İlyax's Turpin mod bot)"
    await member.ban(reason=reason)

    embed = Embed(title="Banning",
                color=discord.Color.red())  # Embed'in rengi (isteğe
    embed.add_field(
      name="Ban Users",
      value=f"This User : {member.mention} is banned for : ``{reason}``",
      inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(
       text="https://turpincheat.glitch.me  --  İlyax.")  # Embed'in alt bilgisi
    await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    channel_id = 1038757871246127134
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)`
```

i did kicking and banning other users in discord

Answer (score 0):

`@commands.has_permissions()` only works on [Bot.command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command).

Here, you're using [app_commands.CommandTree.command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.command) (application / slash command) which uses a different check, [app_commands.checks.has_permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.checks.has_permissions).

```
@bot.tree.command(name="kick", description="Kicking Other Users With My Hammer Tool")
@app_commands.checks.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(interaction, member: discord.Member, reason: str = None):
    ...

@bot.tree.command(name="ban", description="Banning Other Users With My Hammer Tool")
@app_commands.checks.has_permissions(ban_members=True)  # Ban komutunu sadece ban_members yetkisi olan kullanıcıların kullanabilmesini sağlar
async def ban(interaction, member: discord.Member, reason: str = None):
    ...
```

Additionally, you shouldn't be using [discord.Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interaction) as `ctx` because [discord.Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interaction) and [discord.ext.commands.Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) are very different. `ctx.author` becomes `interaction.user`. It still works as long as you use it correctly but it's good practice to properly name variables.

Comment: İ'm get this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 80, in <module>
    @app_commands.checks.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
NameError: name 'app_commands' is not defined

Comment: `app_commands` is from `discord`. Simply, use `discord.app_commands` or `from discord import app_commands`